# Cannot call Thymeleaf HTML page from URL

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new with Thymeleaf. I am using in a Spring Boot Project.
I am trying to render my HTML page lists.html but it displays the "lists" not the page.

I have added the dependency on Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But, it doesn't work ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you using `@Controller` or `@RestController` annotation on the class level?

Comment: Yes I've just realized this. This was the problem!